# Not able to display the the values in ComboBox from the Observable collection created in ViewModel [solved]

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

[image: The only problem is iam not getting my values displayed in my comboBox please help !!!][image: I am getting values in my viewModel Observable collection but combobox is still empty please help]I have a database which contains two Columns `CoourseID` and `Course_Name`. From the Database i am getting my values in my `ObservableCollection` but i am not able to display the values of `ObservableCollection` `FillCourseID` which is bound to `Combobox`. I want `CourseId` and `CourseName` Both displayed in `Combobox`. i referred this link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/explain-combo-box-binding-in-mvvm-wpf/

Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MVVMDemo.UserRegistrationView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:MVVMDemo"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <viewmodel:ViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
        <viewmodel:DatetimeToDateConverter x:Key="MyConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Student.Name, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="76,0"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Age" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Student.Age, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <Button Content="Submit" Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.61,1.96" Margin="0,27.348,0,159.452"/>
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FillCourseId}"  Name="cmb_CourseIDName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="76,5,0,0" 
              Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CourseName}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text=" - "/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CourseID}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

    </ComboBox>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Students}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Width="200" 
                  Margin="27.657,34.948,24.342,159.452">
            <ListView.View >
                <GridView  >
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="60"/>
                    <GridViewColumn  Header="Age" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" Width="60"/>
                    <GridViewColumn  Header="Joining Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding JoiningDate, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" Width="80" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

    </Grid>

</Window>
```

ViewModel Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;


namespace MVVMDemo
{
    public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private Student _student;
        private ObservableCollection<Student> _students;
        private ICommand _SubmitCommand;
        private ObservableCollection<Student> _fillCourseId = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
        static String connectionString = @"Data Source=Ramco-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SIT_Ramco_DB;Integrated Security=True;";
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlCommand cmd;
       // SqlDataAdapter adapter;
       // DataSet ds;
        //SqlDataReader reader;

        public ObservableCollection<Student> FillCourseId
        {
            get { return _fillCourseId; }
            set
            {
                _fillCourseId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SystemStatusData");
            }
        }

        public Student Student
        {
            get
            {
                return _student;
            }
            set
            {
                _student = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Student");
            }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Student> Students
        {
            get
            {
                return _students;
            }
            set
            {
                _students = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Students");
            }
        }

        public ICommand SubmitCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_SubmitCommand == null)
                {
                    _SubmitCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.Submit(),
                        null);
                }
                return _SubmitCommand;
            }
        }

        //********************************************* Functions*******************************************// 

        public void GetCourseIdFromDB()
        {
            try
            {
                con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from dev_Course", con);
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(dt);
               // Student Student = new Student();

                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; ++i)
                    FillCourseId.Add(new Student
                    {
                        CourseID = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString(),
                        CourseName =dt.Rows[i][1].ToString()
                    });

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
        public ViewModel()
        {
            Student = new Student();
            Students = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
            Students.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(Students_CollectionChanged);

        }

        void Students_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Students");
        }

        private void Submit()
        {
            Student.JoiningDate = DateTime.Today.Date;
            Students.Add(Student);
            Student = new Student();
        }
        // Property Changed Event 
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }
    }
}
```

Model Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MVVMDemo
{
    public class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Course { get; set; }
        public string CourseID { get; set; }
        public string CourseName { get; set; }
        public DateTime JoiningDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

i want both `CourseID` and `CourseName` To be displayed in the `combobox`

Comment: You use `FillCourseId` in xaml, but call `OnPropertyChanged("SystemStatusData");` in property setter. You also don't need to call `NotifyPropertyChanged("Students");` when collection changes, because `ObservableCollection` already implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski So what should i do ? What should i bind in displaymemberPath in comboBox in xaml ?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to override the `ToString()` member of the `Student` class to give the `Student` the desired `string` representation:

```
public class Student
{
  public override string ToString() => $"Course Name: {this.CourseName} ({this.CourseID})";

  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }
  public string Course { get; set; }
  public string CourseID { get; set; }
  public string CourseName { get; set; }
  public DateTime JoiningDate { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively bind directly to a `ObservableCollection<string>` and maybe use a `Dictionary<string, Student>` to map the `SelectedItem` to a `Student`
or override the `Style` of the `ComboBox` to display the `SelectedItem` instead of the `SelectionBoxItem` and then set the `ComboBox.ItemTemplate` to add a `DataTemplate` that describes the `ComboBoxItem` to display the required combination of properties with a special layout.

Comment: so should i bind my displaymemberPath with Course Name? I am new to.mvvm and wpf please help

Comment: No, you just leave the binding of the `ItemsSource`as it is (bind to `FillCourseId`). The point is that you want to display a value that is composed of two properties (`CourseID` and `CourseName`). That's why you can use `ToString()` to format the value. Alternatively you can use a `MultiBinding`to compose the value. `DisplayMembrPath` can only point to a single property. Since `MultiBinding` requires a converter implementation, overriding `ToString` is the faster solution. Explanation: when there is no item template defined the`ComboBox`  will call `ToString()` on the items.

Comment: I'm a bit new into mvvm can you please tell how I'm supposed to bind the string in display member path ?

Comment: `DisplayMemberPath` can only point to a single property. `ToString()` is obviously not a property.  You can introduce a new property to support a string composed of several property values. Then reference this property by assigning it to the `DisplayMemberPath` attribute.

Comment: But to display the value returned by `ToString()` you don't need to specify the `DisplayMemberPath`. The `ComboBoc` will automatically call `ToString()` when there is no `ItemTemplate` defined.

Comment: BionicCode can you please explain by some examples.

Comment: Explain what by example? Have you checked your database query? Maybe it never returns values and therefore your `FillCourseId` collection remains empty. Set a break point into `GetCourseIdFromDB` and check if you are entering the `for` loop.

Comment: yes i checked by placing breakpoint . Im getting my values in observable collection.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that GetCourseIdFromDB() was being called earlier in app.xaml.cs class means calling it in different instance. The Change that i made was that I called GetCourseIdFromDB() function inside a cinstructor in ViewModel Class. 
and it fetched the data and displayed in my ComboBox in desired style.

```
public ViewModel()
        {
            Student = new Student();
            Students = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
            Students.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(Students_CollectionChanged);
            GetCourseIdFromDB();
        }
```